# Underdamped free vibration proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I need to prove the solution form of:

$$y''+2cwy'+wy=0$$

My book says, after assuming a solution of the form $Ce^pt$, you can show that:

$$y=[A\sin(wt)+B\sin(sw)] \cdot e^pt$$

I tried using the characteristic equation on the original ODE but it didn't get me anywhere. Any ideas? Obviously, just plugging in the suggested solution isn't a sufficient proof...Any ideas?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should have said $y''+2cwy'+w^2y=0$. Your final solution is also incorrect. You should have persevered with the characteristic equation. Always remember that the general solution has complex coefficients. If you do not allow complex numbers some differential equations will not be solvable via that method. In this case when $(c^2-1)w < 0$ you get complex coefficients. Push ahead and you will be able to factorize out the exponential term, and you can prove that the remaining term is only real when it is sinusoidal.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously, just plugging in the suggested solution isn't a sufficient proof

If for any initial conditions there is a solution of the suggested form, that is a proof, because of the uniqueness of solutions to ODE.  Any differential equation $y'' = f(y,y')$ satisfies the uniqueness theorem for [Lipschitz] continuous $f$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *Lipschitz* continuous $f$, but a linear function is trivially Lipschitz continuous, indeed $C^1$ with bounded derivatives.

Comment: Funny you should mention that.   In phase space with coordinates $(x,y)$, the 2nd order ODE in the answer corresponds to the vector field $(y,f(x,y))$ which I thought of as nonsingular given the first coordinate and the continuity of the second.   But I guess that doesn't work given the ability to imitate the 1st order counterexamples, such as $y'' = h(y')$ with $h$ singular.   So yes, some Lipschitz (uniform?) continuous assumption is necessary.  Thanks for the correction.